# How flexform settings in the repository

Tags: typo3, extbase

I would like to access my flex settings in the repository.

```
this-> settings
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a further parameter to your method in repository and assign the settings with this parameter. 
If you have multiple methods which need these settings, inject the ConfigurationManager in Repository and retrieve Settings with getConfiguration(). See example in AbstractController.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can get flexform settings value in repository file like below.

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$configurationManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');
$extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT);
$settings = $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['plugin.']['tx_extension?key_pluginname.']['settings'];
```